# Specific nested input

Tags: numbering

I have to compile a long article with the following structure:

-Abstract

-Contents

-Preface

-1 article_A (saved in separate folder)

- -1 Introduction (`intro.tex` in folder of A)
- -2 Model (`model.tex` in folder of A)
- -3 Result (`result.tex` in folder of A)
- -4 Reference (BibTeX in folder of A)

-2 article_B (saved in separate folder)

- - (similar structure as A)

-3 article C (save in separate folder)

- - (similar structure as A)

-Conclusion

Actually, new each article can be compiled individually within their own main.tex. But I want to compile them together without modify internal order but taking into account the modification of page numbers.

What I need: Not modify the content of files of A, B, and C; numbers within each article remain the same, don't follow the numbering of articles; table of content shows this structure; at the end of each article there is its own reference (I have BibTeX file in each folder).

I have checked a lot of existing documents online, `import` or `subfiles` packages, or `input`+`include` didn't work. Could anyone please help me?